How to archive iOS app and export unsigned IPA with Xcode 15.4?
I'm trying to export unsigned IPA of an iOS application using Xcode 15.4. This is a bash script I'm using to do so:
xcodebuild clean archive \
  -workspace DemoApp.xcworkspace \
  -scheme DemoApp \
  -configuration Release \
  -sdk "iphoneos" \
  -archivePath DemoApp.xcarchive \
  CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO \
  CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO \
  CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS="" \
  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=""

xcodebuild -exportArchive \
  -archivePath DemoApp.xcarchive \
  -exportPath export \
  -exportOptionsPlist ExportOptions.plist \
  CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO \
  CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO \
  CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS="" \
  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=""

My export options plist looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <false/>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store-connect</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>P38XW29864</string>
    <key>uploadSymbols</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>

The above was working fine with Xcode 15.3 (15E204a), but if I use Xcode 15.4 (15F31d), the following error is thrown when executing xcodebuild -exportArchive:

./build.sh: line 21: 39412 Segmentation fault: 11  xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath DemoApp.xcarchive -exportPath export -exportOptionsPlist ExportOptions.plist CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS="" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=""

The same issue occurs when I try to use Xcode 16.0 beta 1 (16A5171c).
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there any other reliable way of exporting an unsigned IPA of an iOS app?
The minimal Xcode project that reproduces the problem can be found here: https://github.com/darrarski/ios-app-export-unsigned-ipa-example

I am running into the same issue

I was running into a similar segfault issue until I set a provisioningProfiles key with a dict value in the plist.

@IanHunter what did you provide as a value? Could you share an example?

It seems to be fixed in latest beta, but I don’t have an official confirmation, so final version of Xcode 16 could break it again.

@Darrarski I'll post an "answer" since it will look ugly in the comments here

I was running into the same issue until I set a provisioningProfiles dict value in my plist. Here's an example of what I'm using now that no longer segfaults.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store-connect</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>destination</key>
    <string>upload</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.MyAppName</key>
        <string>MyProfileName</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

